# Mocking a Simple DateFormat

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermock

I have a variable  `currentDate =  new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy_HHmmss",Locale.ENGLISH).format(new Date());` inside a class
In testcase I need to mock it. I have tried like this

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy_HHmmss",
            Locale.ENGLISH);
    when(formatter.format(any(Date.class))).thenReturn("18022022_201939");
```

but it is

> giving me cannot format given object as Date

on one machine and on another machine

> it is giving me Date cannot be null.

I am new to Junit and needed help to solve this problem

Comment: Why do you need to mock it? What are you hoping to actually test this way? `SimpleDateFormat` itself is predictable and not worth mocking IMO... if you're trying to test what happens at particular instants in time, I'd recommend injecting a `java.time.Clock` instead - make *that* the replaceable test double, and use `Clock.fixed` in your tests.

Comment: Both `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat` classes are terrible flawed, and are now legacy. They were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Comment: By the way, I recommend use of standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats when exchanging date-time values textually.

Answer (score 0):

As Jon Skeet mentioned it doesn't make sense to mock the `SimpleDateFormat`.
I would suggest validating the date value that is being returned from the method you are testing instead of mocking `SimpleDateFormat`. Something like the test below.

```
    class DateValidator
    {
        String getDate()
        {
            String currentDate = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy_HHmmss", Locale.ENGLISH).format(new Date());
            return currentDate;
        }
    }
    @Test
    public void test()
    {
        String date = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy_HHmmss", Locale.ENGLISH).format(new Date());
        assertThat(new DateValidator().getDate()).isEqualTo(date);

    }
```

Comment: In my main class the currentdate is getting calculated at the middle of processing generates a file with currentdate. I want to assert the file names in the testcase. If I calcutate time in testcase, it will not match with the currentdate from main class So I was trying to mock it

Comment: If the goal is to test the file name that is getting generated with the current date time, still you should be able to create a current date time and test it by creating a time in the test based on the current date time. The only scenario where I see the time could change is if the time it took for creating the contents of the file is huge something like getting data from DB and populating the contents of the file. And if it was the case I would suggest mocking the other processes that are involved other than what you are testing.